# Params from axios.get request are undefined on the express back end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, axios

I'm trying to create a search feature, but when I try to pass data (`params`) to the back end with an `axios.get` request, it is showing `undefined`.

**My react app request handling function:**

```
handleSearch() {
  API.search(this.state.searchType, this.state.searchValue)
  .then(response => { 1 }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

*The above seems to work perfectly as far as I can tell. Those state values are valid and I did test that they were `defined` at this point.*

**My axios/API function:**

```
search: function(searT, searV) {
    let searchData = {
      'searchType': searT,
      'searchValue': searV
    };
    return axios.get('/search', searchData).then(response => 1);
  }
```

*The above appears to be correct according to the `axios docs` and every other resource I've found. The `searT` and `searV` values are passed to this point successfully.*

**Back end `express` function:**

```
app.get('/search', function(request, response) {
    let {searchType, searchValue} = request.params;
    console.log('SearchType: ' + searchType + ' and SearchValue: ' + searchValue); //both return undefined
  });
```

*`searchType` and `searchValue` are `undefined` here, what the heck?!*

I've seen plenty of similar issues out there, but none seem to help me solve this issue. I am wondering if it's something to do with my `server.js` file, but my `axios.post` requests work fine.

I feel like this will be my derp of the week after I figure it out, but for now it's killing me.

**What solved this question, thanks to Montgomery and react-node:**

```
return axios.get('/search', { params: searchData }).then(response => 1);

app.get('/search', function(request, response) {
        let {searchType, searchValue} = request.query;
      });
```

Comment: Should your endpoint be `/search?searchType=x&searchValue=y` or `/search/searchType/searchValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchType` and `searchValue` are getting passed in the query string, so it's necessary to access them with `request.query`.

As pointed out by @react-node, the data was also being passed incorrectly to the `axios.get` call. To correctly pass the query string parameters with `axios.get`, it needs to look like this:

```
return axios.get('/search', {
  params: searchData
}).then(response => 1);
```

Comment: I figured it out. Yes, these two together work.

Although it is strange (though I'm sure there is a technical reason), even though you use `{ params: searchData }` you must still access the data on the back end with `request.query` rather than `request.body` like you would with a similar request using `axios.post` (minus the `{params: object}`.

Answer (score 3):

just change

```
return axios.get('/search', searchData).then(response => 1);
```

to

```
return axios.get('/search', {params:searchData}).then(response => 1);
```

and on the server-side you should change `request.params` to `request.query`

Comment: @Eric Combining this and my answer should work. What happens when you try that?